# To get a data from HTML DOM by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a html DOM like bellow

```
<div class="data">
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('/includes/phoneNumberLookup.cfm?phone=(205) 324-5322&amp;doctorID=2013072910215350207237&amp;url= ' + document.URL + ' &amp;refUrl=','',250,150); return false;">  Click to See Phone Number</a>
</div><div class="data">
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('/includes/phoneNumberLookup.cfm?phone=(205) 324-6577&amp;doctorID=2013072910215350207237&amp;url= ' + document.URL + ' &amp;refUrl=','',250,150); return false;">  Click to See Phone Number</a></div>
```

I want to get the phone number and print it in each of the "data" div, where it should be append li

Phone no- (205) 324-5322

in the first and

Phone no- (205) 324-6577

in the second div.

I have tried like this by help of my previous question.

```
  jQuery('.data').each (function() {
    var self = jQuery(this);
    var phone = "<p> Phone No :-" + jQuery('.data a').attr('onclick').match(/phone\=([0-9\(\) -]+)/)[1] + "</p>";
    jQuery(phone).appendTo( self );
  })
```

But i can not get the result, I need help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use jQuery('this').find('a').attr('onclick')....

Comment: Anyone could think that you are hacking a website to obtain a load of phone numbers...

Answer (score 2):

Just change `jQuery('.data a')` to `self.find('a')` and the result:

```js
  jQuery('.data').each (function() {
    var self = jQuery(this);
    var phone = "<p> Phone No :- " + self.find('a').attr('onclick').match(/phone\=([0-9\(\) -]+)/)[1] + "</p>";
    jQuery(phone).appendTo( self );
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('/includes/phoneNumberLookup.cfm?phone=(205) 324-5322&amp;doctorID=2013072910215350207237&amp;url= ' + document.URL + ' &amp;refUrl=','',250,150); return false;">  Click to See Phone Number</a>
</div><div class="data">
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('/includes/phoneNumberLookup.cfm?phone=(205) 324-6577&amp;doctorID=2013072910215350207237&amp;url= ' + document.URL + ' &amp;refUrl=','',250,150); return false;">  Click to See Phone Number</a></div>
```